# create calendar webform c# & sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Im new to programming and have been assigned a project for class. Basically, i need to make my own calendar from scratch using webforms and sql. It needs to be able to save booking dates.

My instructions:

Calendar View - full month, looks like a calendar, highlight days with bookings available and give brief summary test on days that are booked.  default to current month/year and allow changing to other months/years.

Day View - If booked, show booking information and back button to return to calendar.  If not show new booking form.

New Booking Form - Collect booking info, save and back button.

I was told to use a repeater to make the week portion of the calendar, but i have no clue how to do so. I cant find any examples or tutorials that will guide me. Do you guys have any tips or know of any decent sites to help me out? Im extremely new to programming. Thanks to anyone who can help or guide me in the right direction.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="WeekRepeater" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <table>
         <tr>
              <td id="day0" runat="server"></td>
              <td id="day1" runat="server"></td>
              <td id="day2" runat="server"></td>
              <td id="day3" runat="server"></td>
              <td id="day4" runat="server"></td>
              <td id="day5" runat="server"></td>
              <td id="day6" runat="server"></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: You have to use Repeater, right?. Other wise please try [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16592/Event-Calendar-ASP-NET-2-0-C)

Comment: This is not a do-your-homework site.

Comment: @pravprab thanks for link, i have been reading that one. i asked if i could use the built in calendar, but was told no. i have to make everything from scratch. Im just not sure how to populate my table with all of the days.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to make datasource of repeater
For example

```
 DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Sunday");
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Monday");
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Tuesday");
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Wednesday");
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Thursday");
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Friday");
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Saturday");

         int year = 1995;
        int month = 3;

        int DaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

        int i = 1;
        for (int weak = 0; weak <= 5; weak++)
        {
            DataRow newday = dtSource.NewRow();
            for (int day = 1; day <= 7; day++)
            {
                if (i > DaysInMonth) break;
                 DateTime dDate = DateTime.Parse(i.ToString() + "/" + month .ToString()+ "/" + year.ToString());
                DayOfWeek dayWeek = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(dDate);
                newday[dayWeek.ToString()] = i.ToString();
                i++;
                if (dayWeek.ToString() == "Saturday") break;
            }
            dtSource.Rows.Add(newday);
            if (i > DaysInMonth) break;
        }

        WeekRepeater.DataSource = dtSource;
        WeekRepeater.DataBind();
```

This will Create Calendar for month March 1995

And your repeater will be

```
<asp:Repeater ID="WeekRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Su
                </th>
                <th>
                    Mo
                </th>
                 <th>
                    Tu
                </th>
                <th>
                    Wed
                </th>
                 <th>
                    Thu
                </th>
                <th>
                    Fr
                </th>
                 <th>
                    Sa
                </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Sunday") %>' />
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("Monday") %>' />
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Tuesday") %>' />
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Wednesday") %>' />
            </td>
             <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Thursday") %>' />
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("Friday") %>' />
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label7" Text='<%# Eval("Saturday") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: thank you pravprab. i really appreciate you trying to help. i am not even sure how to use that example you gave - maybe best i give up on this. like i said, im extremely new to any programming/sql server etc. i havent the faintest idea where to begin besides the gui aspect of things. this seems like a very hard thing to build from scratch. but thank you sir. i appreciate your time and help. wish i could give you an upvote =)